# Triangle bisector length problem

Tags: geometry, triangles

I had this task on my math test:

In the triangle ABC, the bisector of angle at C intersects side AB at point D.
Given that the angle at C is 120°, |AB| = 6cm and |BC| = 12cm, calculate the length of bisector |CD|.

I think that such a triangle cannot exist. In every triangle, the largest side is opposite of the largest angle. Thus, as |BC] > |AB|, the angle at A must be greater than the angle at C, which is 120°. From there it follows that the sum of angles in this triangle is larger than 180°, which is impossible.

I am not sure if this makes the task unsolvable...

I would appreciate if you help me solve it or tell me it is impossible to solve (could be that the author made a mistake, e.g. he meant |DB|, not |AB| or something).

Comment: You are right. It should be |AC| = 6cm. Then you can solve it.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give me a hint on how to solve it wih |AC| = 6cm?

Comment: You can use [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem).

Comment: Here we can prove $BD = \frac{BC\times BA}{BC+AC}$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find length of $CD$ where $\angle BCA=120^\circ$ and $CD$ is the bisector of $\angle BCA$ meeting $AB$ at $D$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842649/find-length-of-cd-where-angle-bca-120-circ-and-cd-is-the-bisector-of-a)