# Length of angle bisector using Law of Sines

Tags: trigonometry

> Triangle ABC has angle BAC${}=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and the lengths |AB| and |AC|
>   satisfy $|AC||AB|=1$. Let AD be the angle bisector of BAC. Express the length |AD| as a function of the length |AB|.

I found this problem in an old textbook of mine and was curious if someone could guide me to a solution? There is a suggestion to use the Law of Sines, but frankly, that has led me in circles for hours.

I found a related question: [Find length of $CD$ where $\measuredangle BCA=120^\circ$ and $CD$ is the bisector of $\measuredangle BCA$ meeting $AB$ at $D$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842649/find-length-of-cd-where-angle-bca-120-circ-and-cd-is-the-bisector-of-a), but this does not have the same relationship between the side lengths, and it does not give the answer in terms of the same side.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, nor does it illuminate a solution. Could you please be more detailed and specific?

Comment: There is no reason to believe that the angle bisector is also a perpendicular. Do you have a justification for this?

Comment: It need not be isosceles. In fact, since $|AB|\cdot|AC|=1$, it is most decidedly not isosceles.

Comment: Then my comments are incorrect,shall delete with apology

Answer (score 1):

First of all , let $AB = x$, so :

$BC = \sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^2}+1}$, from ($ABC$-triangle, using cos.theorem)

As we know :
$BD:DC = AB:AC$   - ($1$),

so we get:
$$BD^{2} = x^{2} + AD^{2} -x \cdot AD$$ (cos. theorem from $ABD$-triangle).
 And $BD = \dfrac{x}{\dfrac{1}{x} + x}\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^2}+1}$, from ($1$)

Finally:
$$x^2 + y^2-xy = \frac{x^2}{(x + \frac{1}{x})^2}((x + \frac{1}{x})^{2} - 1)$$ and that's equal to :
$$y^2 -xy + \frac{x^2}{(x + \frac{1}{x})^{2}} = 0$$, which easy to calculate.

Comment: where $y$ is our $AD$

Comment: How do you justify your formula for BC? It looks like it may have come from the Pythagorean Theorem, but which right triangle have you constructed? Also, which angle do you use to justify your use of the Law of Cosines? How do we know the ratio of sides is as you say? Which triangles are you claiming are similar?

Comment: Cosin theorem. I used it twice.

Comment: With which sides and which angles? I still cannot follow your solution.

Comment: @Harold at first time I used cos.theorem I used $BAC$-angle
At second time I used cos.theorem I used $BAD$-angle

Comment: Okay. How do you justify what you labeled (1)? And what side is $y$?

Comment: $y$ is $AD$, I mentioned it 
(1) is famous fact , you could figure it out by yourself (using areas)

Comment: If it is famous, do you know its name? It seems like you are using a similarity argument, but how do you argue the triangles are similar?

Comment: @Harold okay. Consider two triangles : $ABD$ and $CBD$. Their areas :
$S_{ABD} : S_{CBD} = BD : DC = AB \cdot \sin{\angle BAD} : AC \cdot \sin{\angle CAD} = AB : AC$ (because of $\angle BAD = \angle CAD$)

Comment: This proves only that the ratio of the areas is the ratio of AB:AC. You still have not justified that the ratio of the areas is also BD:DC. In any event, I have posted an alternate solution that uses the Law of Sines.

Comment: @Harold it's obvious , because of $DAB$ and $CAD$ has the same attitude

Answer (score 0):

Let $|BD|=x, |DC|=y, \text{and} |AB|=c$ so that $|AC|=\frac{1}{c}$. By the Law of Sines
$$\frac{\sin(C)}{c}=\frac{\sin(2\pi/3)}{x+y}=\frac{\sin(B)}{1/c}.$$
Consequently, 
$$\sin(C)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{c}{x+y}$$
and 
$$\sin(B)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{1/c}{x+y}.$$
Once we bisect angle BAC, we form two new triangles. Let the bisector have length $|AD|=z.$ Using the Law of Sines on the two smaller triangles, we arrive at the following
$$\frac{\sin(\pi/3)}{x} =\frac{\sin(B)}{z} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\sin(\pi/3)}{y} =\frac{\sin(C)}{z}. $$

Substituting from above, we obtain
$$z=\frac{x/c}{x+y} \qquad\text{and}\qquad z= \frac{cy}{x+y}. $$
Multiplying the first equation by $c$ and dividing the second by $c$, we obtain
$$\left(c+\frac{1}{c}\right)z = 1.$$
Recalling our earliest substitutions, this means that
$$|AD|=\frac{1}{|AB|^2+1}.$$